# interface implementations with different concrete types as method parameters

Tags: java, generics

I would like to have a method in an interface that accepts any Type of a generic object, like

```
public void myMethod(List<?>);
```

Now the implementations should only accept a certain type, eg. implementations 1:

```
public void myMethod(List<Integer>);
```

Implementation 2:

```
public void myMethod(List<String>);
```

However this does not work as `public void myMethod(List<Integer>);` is not a valid implementaion of `public void myMethod(List<?>);`

How could I achieve this? (Besides using an Object Parameter and hence rely on casting and do type checking manually)

Comment: Precisely.  If you don't implement a method for `public void MyMethod(List<?>)`, then you haven't implemented the interface (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: By not using an object parameter, do you mean not using myMethod(List<? extends Object>) ? If you want things to be that generic, you will always end up having to do some sort of casting... I might be missing your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious (which happens too much for my liking), why not make the interface itself generic?

```
public interface MyInterface<T> {
   public void myMethod(List<T> list);
}
```

Which can be implemented like so:

```
public class MyClass<T> implements MyInterface<T> {

   @Override
   public void myMethod(List<T> list) {
      // TODO complete this!      
   }

}
```

and used like so:

```
public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      MyClass<String> myString = new MyClass<String>();
      MyClass<Integer> myInt = new MyClass<Integer>();
   }
}
```

Comment: Will have to try but I guess that will work although it puts a bit too much emphasis on the Problem. i'm creating a framework and need a Generic identity field which could be anything from String, to Integer, to UUID or custom type. Depending what the developer using it requires.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to you types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html

for example, use `public void myMethod(List<T>);`

for your interface, and then your concrete classes are instatiated with the type you want.
`

Comment: Yeah i have a class pretty similar to box and the different methods should only accept a certain type of box while the interface is generic